# IE 11 is printing blank page except last page

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, extjs4.2, quirks-mode

I am trying to print [ExtJs 4.2 panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-bbar). 
This panel consists of several [ExtJs grids](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) in `vbox` layout. 
The panel is rendered to a hidden `div` on fly. 
In `afterender` listener of panel, a new window is created using `window.open('')` construct and the hidden `div`'s `innerHTML` is written to the newly created `window.document`. 
The newly created `document` is then closed and printed using regular `window.print` construct.

This arrangement works in the following scenarios:

- In internet explorer, when the panel size is small and can be printed in a single page
- In Chrome browser irrespective of the size of the panel

However as soon as panel grows based on the data stores attached to inner grids, IE prints only the last page and all pages prior to last page are printed as blank pages.

I have tried various IE specific CSS discussed on this forum and other techniques but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured this has something to do with ext-all.css not rendering correctly in IE quirks mode. However I am not sure which classes/rules are causing this.

Comment: I ended up doing away with extjs and wrote a framework to generate regular HTML tables and started printing them. However as a result of I started fixing all of the JS code causing quirk mode rendering.